# Evaluating default arguments in a function python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, default

I have a function with several default arguments like so (arg and default args are all lists):

```
def my_function(arg1, default1=None, default2=None, default3=None):


    if not default1:
        dosomething1 = dictionary[arg1]

    if not default2:
        dosomething2 = variable.copy()

    if not default3:
        dosomething3 = variable2.copy()


    proj = another_function(arg1, dosomething1, dosomething2, dosomething3)

    return proj
```

I'd like to add another if statements that looks like this:

```
if not (default1 or default2 or default3):
    dosomething1 = dictionary[arg1]
    dosomething2 = variable.copy()
    dosomething3 = variable2.copy()
```

but keep getting the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` that points to the line under the`if not default1:` statement.  My question is how can I use `my_function()` when only `arg1` is specified?

Comment: what is `dictionary`, `variable` and `variable2`, they seem to be global variables but are undefined in your question.

Comment: `dictionary` is a dictionary of lists where `arg1` will always be a key and `variable1` and `variable 2` are lists that provide "fall-back" values if `default1` and `default2` aren't specified.

Comment: Please [edit] them into the question, if they are too long then just show the first 5-10 entries. :) Without a [mcve] any answer would have to guess what you tried to do and what you expected. So we will also need the command how you called your function. :)

Comment: `unhashable type` usually shows up when you try to index a dictionary with something that can't be used to index a dictionary. Is `arg1` a list? Because you can't use a list to index a dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @e9e9s You said that all the parameters are lists, but also say that `dictionary` is guaranteed to have `arg1` as a key (you actually said `arg` but that's not a thing in your code). That's not possible, since you can't use a `list` as a key to a dictionary.

Comment: try getting rid of the parentheses in the statement. Parens have a different meaning in Python

Comment: @jollarvia I'm not sure what you think the parens are doing there, but it looks like his logic is working right (if none of the following are truthy: default1, deafult2, or default3, execute this block). Without the parens the logic becomes "if default is Falsey, or default2 is Truthy, or default3 is Truthy: execute the block"

Comment: @jollarvia Not really. Only if he wanted to construct tuples (but he doesn't).

Comment: Then it has to be the dictionary. But why would it be different in the two snippets unless a different type is used for arg1 in both

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are trying to lookup a dict using list as the key, that is not allowed as the list is not hashable

Looks like , from your comments , you wanted to add the `arg1` list as value to the `dictionary`. Then you should be doing something like

```
dictionary['some-key'] = arg1
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he didn't want to add it to the dictionary given that he passes `doSomething1` to the inner function.